# Generate a NumPy array with powers of 2

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Usually when creating certain sequences of numbers, python and numpy offer some syntactic sugar to do so in a simple way, without generating them yourself with for-loops, e.g. `range(start, stop, step)`.

I'm having a rather simple problem that I'm struggling to solve in an elegant way: Generate a list of the powers of two. E.g. `list = [1, 2, 4, 8, ...]`.

I came up with

```
n_powers = 4
list = np.zeros(n_powers)
for i in range(0, n_powers): 
    list[i] = 2 ** i
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "Better" how?  What shortcomings do you observe in the solution you have now?

Comment: `list` **is not a `list`** it is a `numpy.ndarray`. These are two different data-structures that typically have different idiomatic approaches to doing things. If your `list` variable were indeed a `list` object, this would be a perfectly reasonable way of doing it, except you would normally use `.append` on an empty list, and not pre-allocate it.

Comment: Also don't use `list` as a variable name because your overwrite the built-in type `list` then.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You seem to be using NumPy, so why not just do this -

```
>>> 2 ** np.arange(4)
array([1, 2, 4, 8])
```

This is broadcasted exponentiation.

Comment: Cool, something like this is what I was looking for - my mistake was not using numpy before. I tried: `list = range(0,4)` and then `list = 2 ** list` gave me an error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'`

Comment: @Honeybear Yes, because pure python lists do not support vectorized arithmetic.

Comment: 2 ** np.array() vs np.array() ** 2 gives different results

Comment: well, yes, if you think about it, it makes perfect sense. The first expression raises 2 to the power of the elements in the array, the second expression raises the elements in the array to the power of 2. @Edi

Answer (score 8):

Maybe just:

```
l = [2**i for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
limit = int(input('Limit: '))
l = []

for i in range(limit):
    l.append(2**i)
```

It is also good to not use `list` as a variable as is is a datatype and has a built-in list() function

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.power.html), you can use power() function to increase to desired power in numpy.

i.e. to increase in the power of 2 you can use this:  `np.power(np.arange(4), 2)`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your question is
You can just do:

```py
n_powers = 4
list = []
for i in range(n_powers):
    list.append(2 ** i)
print(list)
```

Comment: as @Crawley said, it is better not to use list as a variable but it still works.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of this problem (powers of 2) you can use the following Numpy method.

```
np.exp2(np.arange(4))

Out: array([1., 2., 4., 8.])
```